# PrimeFaces :: display p:Dialog to fill-in a form field, without reposting

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a data-entry form that displays a number of fields (mostly **p:inputText**) for the user to provide. Some of these are LOVs so I display a **p:dialog** to allow the user to select the right value. The **p:dialog** is displayed by means of a **p:commandLink** next to the **p:inputText**. Main parts of code shown below:

```
<h:form id="parentForm">
    (...)
    <p:inputText value="#{CustomerCEVController.customer.municipality}" id="customerMncName"/>
    <p:commandLink type="button" onclick="MunicipalityDlg.show()" styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-search"/>
    (...)
    <p:commandButton value="Submit"  id="save" actionListener="#{CustomerCEVController.saveButtonListener}" /> (...)
</h:form>
```

The problem is, whenever the user clicks on the **p:commandLink** to display the **p:dialog** (to allow him to select one of the values) the outer form goes through its lifecycle phases (restore view, apply request values, process validations, etc.) since the **p:commandLink** is placed inside an **h:form**. How can I implement this dialog-displaying functionality while avoiding posting the **h:form** with every dialog that the user opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "return false" as the last statement to onclick event handler. It prevents commandLink's default function (posting the form).

Answer (score 1):

Just add set the `appendToBody` attribute to true on `<p:dialog>`

```
<p:dialog header="Header Text" widgetVar="dlg" appendToBody="true">
   //Content
</p:dialog>
```

This appends the dialog as a child of the document body outside the parent form.