# Primefaces dialog fields not filled after click in CommandLink

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I am using Primefaces 3.5 with Weblogic 11. I have a page where a dialog to edit a 'profile' entity ('perfil' in Portuguese) which is called from two places. First from a commandButton to insert a new profile. The second from a dataTable to edit a specific profile. Below, I show the code:

Snippet of XHTML page

```
<p:fieldset legend="Pesquisa de Perfil">
    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <p:commandButton id="btnPesquisar"
                actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.pesquisar}" value="Pesquisar"
                immediate="true" update="pnlPerfis" styleClass="ui-icon-search" />
            <p:spacer width="20"></p:spacer>
            <!-- OPEN DIALOG TO CREATE A NEW PROFILE -->
            <p:commandButton id="btnIncluir" value="Incluir"
                update="dlgPerfil" immediate="true"
                actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.abrirDialogoEdicao(null)}"
                oncomplete="dlgPerfil.show();">
            </p:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:fieldset>

<br />

<p:outputPanel id="pnlPerfis" layout="block">
    <p:fieldset id="resultadoPesquisa" legend="Resultado da Pesquisa"
        rendered="#{not empty perfilAcessoMB.perfis}">
        <p:dataTable id="tblPerfis" value="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfis}"
            var="perfil" emptyMessage="Nenhum perfil encontrado.">
            <p:column headerText="Nome do Perfil">
                <h:outputText value="#{perfil.nome}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Descrição do Perfil">
                <h:outputText value="#{perfil.descricao}"></h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Situação do Perfil"
                style="text-align: center; width: 100px;">
                <h:outputText value="Ativo" rendered="#{perfil.situacao}" />
                <h:outputText value="Inativo" rendered="#{not perfil.situacao}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Editar"
                style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">
                <!-- OPEN DIALOG TO EDIT A NEW PROFILE -->
                <p:commandLink id="lnkEditar" immediate="true"
                    title="Editar Perfil" update=":formPrincipal:dlgPerfil :formPrincipal:pnlPerfilEdicao"
                    actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.abrirDialogoEdicao(perfil)}"
                    oncomplete="dlgPerfil.show();">
                    <h:outputText value="Editar" />
                </p:commandLink>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Excluir"
                style="text-align: center; width: 50px;">
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:fieldset>

</p:outputPanel>

<p:dialog id="dlgPerfil" widgetVar="dlgPerfil" resizable="false"
    closable="true" modal="true" closeOnEscape="true"
    header="#{(empty perfilAcessoMB.perfil)? 'Incluir': 'Editar'} Perfil">
    <h:outputText value="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfil}"></h:outputText>
    <h:panelGroup id="pnlPerfilEdicao" layout="block">
        <p:fieldset legend="Dados do Perfil">
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel id="lblNomePerfilEdicao" value="Nome do Perfil"
                    for="txtNomePerfilEdicao" />
                <p:inputText id="txtNomePerfilEdicao" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="É obrigatório preencher o campo Nome do Perfil."
                    value="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfil.nome}" maxlength="20" size="20"></p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel id="lblDescricaoPerfilEdicao"
                    value="Descrição do Perfil" for="txtDescricaoPerfilEdicao" />
                <p:inputText id="txtDescricaoPerfilEdicao" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="É obrigatório preencher o campo Descrição do Perfil."
                    value="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfil.descricao}" maxlength="20"
                    size="20"></p:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel id="lblSituacaoPerfilEdicao" value="Situação"
                    for="selSituacaoPerfilEdicao" />
                <p:selectOneMenu id="selSituacaoPerfilEdicao"
                    value="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfil.situacao}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{perfilAcessoMB.situacoesEdicao}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:fieldset>
        <br />
        <p:fieldset legend="Permissões">
            <p:pickList id="pickFuncoes" value="#{perfilAcessoMB.funcoes}"
                var="funcao" itemValue="#{funcao}"
                itemLabel="#{funcao.descricao}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="É obrigatório associar ao menos uma funcionalidade ao perfil."
                converter="funcaoConverter" />
            <p:column>#{funcao.descricao}</p:column>
        </p:fieldset>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:commandButton id="btnSalvarPerfil" value="Salvar"
                actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.salvar}"
                oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) dlgPerfil.hide();" />
            <p:commandButton id="btnCancelarPerfil" value="Cancelar"
                immediate="true" onclick="dlgPerfil.hide();" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGroup>
</p:dialog>
```

MangedBean (perfilAcessoMB)

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PerfilAcessoMB extends BaseMB {

    private PerfilAcessoORM perfil;

    private List<PerfilAcessoORM> perfis;

    private String nomePerfil;

    private Boolean situacao;

    private DualListModel<FuncaoORM> funcoes;

    private SelectItem[] situacoesPesquisa = new SelectItem[] {
            new SelectItem(null, "Todos"), SELECT_ITEM_ATIVO,
            SELECT_ITEM_INATIVO };

    private SelectItem[] situacoesEdicao = new SelectItem[] {
            SELECT_ITEM_ATIVO, SELECT_ITEM_INATIVO };

    private FuncaoORM funcaoA = new FuncaoORM(1L, "FUNÇÃO A"), //
            funcaoB = new FuncaoORM(2L, "B Function"), //
            funcaoC = new FuncaoORM(10L, "Se Funssaum");

    public void abrirDialogoEdicao(PerfilAcessoORM p) {
        this.perfil = (p == null)? new PerfilAcessoORM(): p;
        System.out.println("PerfilAcessoMB.onAbrirDialogoEdicao(): "
                + this.perfil);

        List<FuncaoORM> funcoesDisponiveis = new ArrayList<FuncaoORM>(
                Arrays.asList(funcaoA, funcaoB, funcaoC));
        // Remove from funcoesDisponiveis those whose are present in perfil.
        if (this.perfil.getFuncoes() == null) {
            this.funcoes = new DualListModel<FuncaoORM>(funcoesDisponiveis,
                    Lists.<FuncaoORM> newArrayList());
        } else {
            funcoesDisponiveis.removeAll(this.perfil.getFuncoes());
            this.funcoes = new DualListModel<FuncaoORM>(funcoesDisponiveis,
                    this.perfil.getFuncoes());
        }
    }

    // Getters & Setters

}
```

PerfilAcessoORM (Profile) Entity

```
public class PerfilAcessoORM  {

    private Long id;

    private String nome;

    private String descricao;

    private Boolean situacao = null;

    private List<FuncaoORM> funcoes;

    // Getters & Setters

}
```

FuncaoORM Entity:

```
public class FuncaoORM {

    private Long id;

    public String descricao;

    // Getters & Setters

}
```

What is my problem? Apparently, when I want insert a new Profile, all seems OK. However, when I click to edit an existent profile to open the dialog, although the `outputText` and `pickList` are correctly filled, the `inputText`'s and `selectOneMenu` are not.

Looking for solutions, I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738355/primefaces-display-pdialog-to-fill-in-a-form-field-without-reposting) a suggestion to use `appendToBody="true"` in dialog. When I tried, the `inputText`'s and `selectOneMenu` are correctly filled. However, the validation is not working as waited. When I click to save it is showed a message indicating that pickList is not filled, even if it is really filled. Actually, even if `inputText`'s are not filled, there is no message about these `inputText`s although they are required.

Another alternative would be use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` inside `commandLink`:

```
<!-- OPEN DIALOG TO CREATE A NEW PROFILE -->
<p:commandButton id="btnIncluir" value="Incluir"
    update="dlgPerfil" immediate="true"
    actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.abrirDialogoEdicao}"
    oncomplete="dlgPerfil.show();">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfil}" value="#{null}"/>
</p:commandButton>


<!-- OPEN DIALOG TO EDIT A NEW PROFILE -->
<p:commandLink id="lnkEditar" immediate="true"
    title="Editar Perfil" update=":formPrincipal:dlgPerfil :formPrincipal:pnlPerfilEdicao"
    actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.abrirDialogoEdicao}"
    oncomplete="dlgPerfil.show();">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{perfilAcessoMB.perfil}" value="#{perfil}"/>
    <h:outputText value="Editar" />
</p:commandLink>
```

The actionListener method would changed to:

```
public void abrirDialogoEdicao() {
    if(this.perfil == null) {
        this.perfil = new PerfilAcessoORM();
    }
    System.out.println("PerfilAcessoMB.onAbrirDialogoEdicao(): "
            + this.perfil);
    // The rest remains the same ...
}
```

Now, when I click to create a new perfil, although in actionListener method the perfil attribute is filled, I got a NullPointerException when the dialog is renderized. It is like first is called `perfilAcessoMB.setPerfil()`, after the dialog is opened and finally actionListener method. On the other hand, if I click to edit an existent profile, I return to initial situation.

Therefore, I am lost, without idea how to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was incredible simple: just added `process="@this"` to both commandButtons.

```
<!-- OPEN DIALOG TO EDIT A NEW PROFILE -->
<p:commandLink id="lnkEditar" immediate="true"
    title="#{msg['titulo.edicao']}" process="@this"
    update=":formPrincipal:dlgPerfil"
    actionListener="#{perfilAcessoMB.abrirDialogoEdicao(perfil)}"
    oncomplete="dlgPerfil.show();">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['titulo.edicao']}" />
</p:commandLink>
```